# Google maps api v2. Failed to Load Map. Could not connect to google servers

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I an getting this error when I run the application on the real device.

Main_Activity.java,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int chkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context);
    if (chkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(chkGooglePlayServices,
                (Activity) Context, 1122).show();
    } else {
        SupportMapFragment sfm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = sfm.getMap();

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        // Location Update
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mMap.clear();
                final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                .getLongitude())).zoom(14.0f).build();
                final CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
                mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context)
                    .setTitle(R.string.RemindEnableGps);
            AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alert.setCancelable(true);
                alert.show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                alert.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }
        };

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                listener);
        final Location mLocation = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        /*final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation
                        .getLongitude())).zoom(14.0f).build();
        final CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);*/
    }

}
```

This is my mainifest file,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.findproperty"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.findproperty.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.findproperty.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.findproperty.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Given my signed key" />

   </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have imported Google play libraries required for the app. Map object is not null. But in the logcat it displays "Google maps Api v2 Failed to load map. Could not connect to google servers"

What I am missing? Please anyone help!! This is killing me!!

Comment: It's possibly not the root of your issue, but try using <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" /> instead of <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />. Also, did you turn on your API key in Google console?

Comment: also you include a permission twice in your manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="com.example.findproperty.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />. Remove the one without the android:protectionLevel="signature" tag

Comment: Yes granted the permission in api console.

Comment: sounds like something trivial... like wifi disabled on device or a mix-up with the api-key

Comment: I assume your device is connected to the internet...

Comment: Yes connected to internet. Wi-Fi is on. Unable to find where the problem has raised.

Comment: How did you solve this? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest implies you have entered your signed api key as the google api key, so I assume you're testing this by installing a signed apk on to the device and not running the app signed with the debug key via eclipse. Is this correct?

Problems like this with API access often come down to an input error with the api key, or an error during the hashing process.

I would make sure that the key in your manifest is correct.

Comment: Signed with the android debug key? or with your own created key?

Comment: So was the map working when you were testing it through eclipse?
When did the error occurring?

Comment: Placed the created key in the manifest file. Map is not displaying.

Comment: Do I need to give MD5 fingerprint or SHA1 fingerprint for creating api key?

Comment: You need to provide SHA1

But you also need to ensure you're getting the SHA1 from hashing the android debug key if you're running the app via an IDE. If you're running the app with an exported apk signed with your own certificate you need to provide the SHA1 signature of that certificate.